# Loop Using Symbols to Compare Hash to Array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, symbols

I'm trying to compare a hash's key to the contents of an array. If it is match, I want the item deleted from the hash.

```
allocate = {:item1=>[1, 1], :item2=>[1, 2], :item3=>[1, 3]}

bad = [:item2, :item4]
```

This works great:

```
allocate.tap{ |h| h.delete(:item1)}
allocate
=> {:item2=>[1, 2], :item3=>[1, 3]}
```

If I call a value from the "bad" array, the values are returned as strings, not as a symbol.

```
bad[1]
=> "item4"
```

This also happens with loops:

```
bad.each do |bad|
  allocate.tap{ |h| h.delete(bad)}
  puts bad
end

=> "item2"
=> "item4"

allocate
=> {:item1=>[1, 1], :item2=>[1, 2], :item3=>[1, 3]}
```

I want to keep the hash key and the array as symbols for performance reasons. What do I need to do to access the "bad" array and keep the items as symbols so I can properly compare it to the allocate hash?

I'm using Ruby v 2.1.3p242.

Comment: "If I call a value from the "bad" array, the values are returned as strings, not as a symbol." - try double checking this assumption. It shouldn't be true. Try a simple Ruby program with `puts [:item2, :item4][1] == :item4`

Comment: Are you sure you have a problem? `bad = [:item2, :item4] 
 => [:item2, :item4]`. Then `bad[1] => :item4` and `p bad[1]` 
prints `:item4`, but `puts bad[1]` prints `"item4"`. Where you say `bad[1]
=> "item4"` are you sure that wasn't `puts bad[1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
allocate = {:item1=>[1, 1], :item2=>[1, 2], :item3=>[1, 3]}   
bad = [:item2, :item4]

bad.each {|k| allocate.delete(k) }
allocate # => {:item1=>[1, 1], :item3=>[1, 3]}
```

"bad" values are symbols. Use `p` to check them.

```
p bad[0] # prints => :item2
p bad[1] # prints => :item4
```

Don't use `puts` to debug as it convert symbols to string before printing them

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_sym` to translate strings into symbols. Btw there is no need to use `tap`:

```
bad.each { |key| allocate.delete(key.to_sym) }
```

Or:

```
allocate.delete_if { |key, _| bad.map(&:to_sym).include?(key) }
```